# Chrome extension machine wide storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm currently developing a chrome extension. To authenticate users, I create at extension add a random id and then save it into local storage to be then compared with the copy present on a remote server. I would like the extension to be available to all the chorme instances present on the machine, regardless of which Google account they belong to. Is there any way to have data saved that is then accessible to the same extension installed on different chrome instances?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's no such API for extensions but you can use a file via [File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API). The handle of the file, once obtained via this API, can be saved in IndexedDB so the user will only have to confirm it once.

Comment: @wOxxOm what exactly user would have to confirm?

Comment: The file's location. See the documentation for more info.

Comment: Share maybe some of you code to make it easier to give a good answer.